# Ambiguous use of title - Xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, xcode9-beta

Xcode 9 beta compiler shows the following error for the `navigationItem.title` and also for the `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title`:

> Ambiguous use of 'title'

This is my code:

```
self.title = BMLocalized("Select Number of Passengers")
navigationItem.title = navigationTitleString // here showing error
submitButton.setTitle(submitButtonTitle, for: .normal)
```

[image: error screenshot]

Can anyone help for solving this issue?

Comment: Can you pls share some code?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        BM_CustomBackButton.createBackButton(&self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, responder: self, type: BM_CustomBackButtonType.backWhiteArrow)
        
        self.title = BMLocalized("Select Number of Passengers")
        navigationItem.title = navigationTitleString

Comment: @Nagar Don't add code in comment edit your question and add code in it

Comment: Just try with `navigationItem.title = "Demo"`, because I can't see any error.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon its not working any other solution?

Comment: @Nagar What is the type of `navigationTitleString`?

Comment: var navigationTitleString : String? // String optional and I also tried "Demo" instead of  "navigationTitleString"

Comment: Can you pls share screenshot with a n error?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon added error screenshot in Q

Comment: I don't know what's the issue, But check this out it has no error. https://ibb.co/d5CUTF

Comment: @SohilR.Memon can it be due to some pod file because I am using "Material" ?

Comment: I can't say that without any confirmation.

Comment: @Nagar, yes, it is because you use "Material". See my solution  below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Just use this code:

```
navigationItem.titleLabel.text = "text"
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

It happen because you use third party library which extends UINavigationItem class and reimplements property *title*. So, this library conflict with UIKit.

Solution:

Just use

```
title
```

instead of

```
navigationItem.title
```

Or remove extension of UINavigationItem class in the third-party library. The name of this library you can see in the issue navigator:

[image: error]

For MATERIAL solution is:

remove from Material -> Core -> NavigationItem.swift those lines:

```
public var title: String? {
    get {
        return titleLabel.text
    }
    set(value) {
        titleLabel.text = value
        navigationItem.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't update title field for me when using code:
              titleNavigationItem = UINavigationItem.init(title: "AAA")
        navigationBar.items?.removeAll()

        navigationBar.items?.append(titleNavigationItem )
        titleNavigationItem.titleLabel.text = "sup bro"

Comment: EDIT: Only material solution works. One from update doesn't :(

Answer (score 2):

For now, instead of modifying the source code, you can also use this:

```
navigationItem.titleLabel.text = "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use,

self.title = "title_name"

instead of both, and if you use both then it will replace from one another.